Folder and Sub-Folder Size for Network Drive
I need to see an active list of folders in my Network Drive INCLUDING the folder size. When I expend a directory, I want to see folder size for all Sub-Folders.
Requirement: Network Drive!
Great Solution for Local Drive is WinDirStat
Windows 11 OS

have you tried mapping the network drive to a drive letter and checking it with windirstat? it works for me.

Wiztree allows you to select a folder or network drive

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Frank, it is mapped to a drive letter.
I did find the program "TreeSize" that did exactly what I was looking for.
